# C# MSSQL Что необходимо для запуска?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Создал проект windows forms с .NET v4.0, добавил в проект *Service-based Database*, назвал **Database.mdf**.

Я хочу запустить приложение на другом компьютере, кроме .NET v4.0, что мне еще необходимо установить для корректной работы с MDF базой?  Локально все работает, на других компьютерах нет.

Ошибки:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

Строка подключения к базе:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы используете SQL Server Local DB - он не требует установки как сервиса, но требует ручного создания экземпляра сервера из командной строки.

> The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

Эта ошибка означает, что экземпляра с именем MSSQLLocalDB не существует. Его надо создать, из консоли:

```
sqllocaldb c MSSQLLocalDB
```

---

Local DB предназначен прежде всего для разработки. Для живого развертывания приложения стоит использовать полноценный SQL Server.