# Запуск приложения использующего localdb на разных компьютерах

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-localdb

Я написал приложение на языке C#, которое работает с базой данных MS SQL. Если я переношу приложение на другой компьютер и пытаюсь запустить то оно не работает т.к. там отсутствует БД с которой я работаю. Как сделать чтобы при запуске программы на разных компьютерах БД устанавливалась автоматически?

Comment: Вы можете использовать подключение MS SQL к файлу, положить файл базы данных в проект и распространять вместе со своим приложением. Однако такой вариант все равно будет требовать наличия SQL Server на машине клиента, хотя бы Express версия, ну и разумеется, если БД совсем маленькая и не содержит сложных связей и логики, то лучше использовать что-то по-легче.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# MSSQL Что необходимо для запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603435/c-mssql-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы немного не так используете SQL базу. Данная база устанавливается на сервере и ваше приложение соединяется не с самой базой, а с сервером. А он уже в свою очередь и работает с БД.

Если же вам нужно чтобы данные хранились рядом с приложением, то используйде [SQLITE](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Как для примера использования [пример 1](http://www.sergechel.info/ru/content/using-sqllite-with-c-sharp-part-1-preparing-tools) [пример 2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/56694/)

Comment: У меня возможен выбор только из MS SQL и MySQl. С какой из них тогда лучше работать?

Comment: Дело не в том с какой работать лучше, а в том, зачем они вам нужны. С базами данных типа MySQl, PostgreSQL и др. Так не работают. Их не таскают рядом с приложением. Они лежат на сервере (металический такой ящик) к этим БД подключен сервер (такая програма вами написанная - это не металический ящик, а другое, просто называется так же) и уже сервер работает с БД и отдает данные вашему приложению.

Если же вы хотите чтоб рядом с приложением была БД, то нужно использовать  SQLITE, она для этого и написана была в принципе.

Comment: В домашних условиях вобще реально на ноутбуке разместить сервер и там хранить эту БД?

Comment: Если вы про MySQl, PostgreSQL и иже с ними то, да конечно. Можно установить любую из них, написать для работы с ней сервер и запускать его локально. А потом уже, когда творение будет готово - выкладывать на арендованный сервер и там разворачивать. (можно облако использовать - тут дело вкуса и поставленных задач)

Опять же, при использовании  SQLITE подход немного другой. Это база больше для обслуживания самого приложения и данных только одного этого приложения. Например в ней можно хранить какие-то данные пользователя, размещать подгруженные (опять же с сервера) новости и т.п.

Comment: @Denis, есть "переносная" версия БД, называется MS SQL Server CE, представляет собой библиотеку, подключаемую к приложению, отлично подходит для "однопользовательского" хранилища, вся БД помещается в один файл, который можно таскать хоть на флешке

Comment: Также есть, например, embedded server у Firebird, что-то однопользовательское есть и у MySQL, вроде

Comment: Да много чего есть. Я писал уже, что БД выбирается под свои задачи. 

Но вы должны понимать, что при использовании таких БД, вы не сможете объединить данные для разных пользователей. И пользователь одной копии вашего приложения не сможет синхронизовать данные с данными в другом приложении(хотя если сильно захотеть :))).

MS SQL Server CE это частное развертывание исполняемого модуля в папке приложения.

Comment: Не соглашусь, SQLite конечно модно и молодежно, особенно для мобильных платформ, но если говорить о Win-платформе, то SQL Express и LocalDb способны переварить гораздо бОльшие по объему и сложности данные, и при этом будут работать с единственным файлом, который поставляется с приложением. К тому же в последних версиях Win, LocalDb обычно уже стоит, т.к. используется внутренними службами

Answer (score 1):

Денис , [code first](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.2.php), почитатите тут , есть ещё видео на ютубе , там у человека все подробно описано 
При таком подходе приложение само создает базу данных , если необходимый SQL установлен на другой машине